# tight_layout with gridspec and shared x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Still new to python so I am still trying to learn and become better. The initial problem was that the y-labels for my gridspec did not stay within the figure size, so I tried to call the tight_layout which solved the initial problem but created another

The problem seems to be that my 1. gridspec which initially have a shared x-axis and stays in 1 "figure" separates into 2 figures when I call the tight_layout command. Can I still have tigh_layout or do I need to have another code for my y-labels to stay within figure size?

To produce the following figure I use the code:

```
        colors = ["tab:blue", "#ed7d74", "#71bf82", "#000000", "C4", "C5", "C6"]
        fig = plt.figure(figsize = (13,7))
        #gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, hspace=0, height_ratios=[2,1])
        gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(2, hspace=0, left=0.05, right=0.6, height_ratios=[2,1])
        axs1 = gs1.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=False)
        #fig.suptitle(lgn[idx])
        
        mark_size = 3
        
        
        axs1[0].plot(t, U, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[1], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].plot(t0, U0, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].plot(t1, U1, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].plot(t2, U2, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].plot(t3, U3, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].plot(t4, U4, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 1)
        axs1[0].set(ylabel="Potential [V]")
        axs1[0].grid(alpha = 0.3)
        
        axs1[0].set_ylim(min(U)-0.1, max(U)+0.1)
        axs1[1].plot(t, j, '-', markersize = 2, color = colors[2], alpha = 1)
        axs1[1].grid(alpha = 0.3)
        axs1[1].set(ylabel="j [mA cm$^{-2}$]")
        axs1[1].set(xlabel="Time [hours]")
        axs1[1].set_ylim(0, max(j)+50)
        
        
        
        
        
        gs2 = fig.add_gridspec(2, hspace=0.03, left=0.65, right=0.98, top=0.98, bottom=0.02, height_ratios=[2,1])
        axs2 = gs2.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=False)
        
        axs2[0].plot(t[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+15], U[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+15], '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[1], alpha = 0.6)
        axs2[0].plot(t4, U4, '.', markersize = mark_size, color = colors[0], alpha = 0.6)
        #axs2[0].set(ylabel="Potential [V]")
        axs2[0].grid(alpha = 0.3)
        axs2[0].set_xlim(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], t[IDX4_e+(12*36)+10])
        axs2[1].plot(t[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+15], j[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+15], '-', markersize = 2, color = colors[2], alpha = 0.6)
        axs2[1].grid(alpha = 0.3)
        #axs2[1].set(ylabel="j [mA cm$^{-2}$]")
        axs2[1].set(xlabel="Time [hours]")
        
        axs2[0].set_yticklabels([])
        axs2[1].set_yticklabels([])
        
        axs1[0].fill_between((t[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+15]), axs2[0].get_ylim()[0], axs2[0].get_ylim()[1], facecolor=(0,0,0,0.1), edgecolor=(0,0,0,1), zorder = 20)
        axs1[1].fill_between((t[IDX4_s-(4*35):IDX4_e+(12*35)+10]), axs2[1].get_ylim()[0]+10, axs2[1].get_ylim()[1], facecolor=(0,0,0,0.1), edgecolor=(0,0,0,1), zorder = 20)# facecolor=colors[3], alpha=0.1)
        
        con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[0].get_ylim()[0]), coordsA=axs1[0].transData, xyB=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[0].get_ylim()[0]), coordsB=axs2[0].transData, color = colors[3])
        fig.add_artist(con1)
        con2 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[0].get_ylim()[1]), coordsA=axs1[0].transData, xyB=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[0].get_ylim()[1]), coordsB=axs2[0].transData, color = colors[3])
        fig.add_artist(con2)
        
        con3 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[1].get_ylim()[0]+10), coordsA=axs1[1].transData, xyB=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[1].get_ylim()[0]), coordsB=axs2[1].transData, color = colors[3])#, linestyle='--')
        fig.add_artist(con3)
        con4 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[1].get_ylim()[1]), coordsA=axs1[1].transData, xyB=(t[IDX4_s-(4*35)], axs2[1].get_ylim()[1]), coordsB=axs2[1].transData, color = colors[3])
        fig.add_artist(con4)
```

[image]

When I add this code I get the following figure

```
        gs1.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.6, 1.0])
        gs2.tight_layout(fig, rect=[0.65, 0.02, 0.98, 0.98])
```

[image]

As you can see the figure on left splits into 2 figures - can this be solved ?

Comment: Your terminology isn't correct -- you will have trouble finding solutions online (e.g. via search engine) if your are not precise. What you show is a single *figure* with multiple *subplots* or *panels* which happened to be aligned so that there is no gap between them. Subplots having a *shared x axis* means that their value ranges are linked, not that they are positioned in a specific way within the figure.

Comment: Ahh I see, still having a hard time choosing the right terminology for presenting problems. But I see your point , this is what I am trying to describe with the no gap - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `tight_layout()` in this specific case, why don't you use [`subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) to change the margins?

E.g. run

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, bottom=.2, right=.8, top=.8)
```

which will give you a lot of space around your panels, and then decrease / increase the values until it looks good.

Comment: This apparently only works for the vertical position on the left side of subplots. But this gave me the idea of just using gs1.update(left=.2, bottom=.2, right=.8, top=.8) and gs2.update(xxxxx) and then decrease/increase values until it looks good.